# Displaying a confirmation screen from notification action on Android Wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I'm trying to display a confirmation screen on Android Wear after an action has been selected.

The action has been added using the `WearableExtender` as outlined in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#ActionButtons) article.

There seems to be a `setConfirmLabel(CharSequence label)` method inside `Notification.Action.WearableExtender`, however, it doesn't seem to do anything.

I thought I would try make the action fire an IntentService to send a message to the Wear device which would bring up it's own confirmation Activity though there is still that green tick to mark the action as successful in between.

Another way would be to set the notification to local only and send a message to Wear to construct its own notification so it could start a confirmation activity, but then the notification would only appear if the device was connected at the time (e.g. walking back into range won't show the notification automatically).

Is it possible to have a screen like the voice control `RemoteInput` act as a confirmation to actions?